# Unable to upload video longer than 6 - 7 mins to server in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video, asihttprequest

I am trying to upload large files from my app to web server using a web service.

I am reading the video into an `NSData` instance and converting that into a base64 encoded string. I then pass the string to webservice. I even tried degrading the quality of video to low while uploading still I am not able to upload video above 5 min on server, the server just stops responding.

When I check the encoded data from server it is not receiving it completely. I think the size of the file is so large that it's not getting sent properly. Below is some of my code. I tried many options mentioned in many posts but still am not able to upload videos properly as per my client's requirement. I have successfully uploaded videos up to 4 to 5 mins long with low quality but not able to upload big videos. Please help me out.

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlVideo];
pictureDataString = [videoData base64Encoding];

----other code 

xml = [xml stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<BinaryData>%@</BinaryData>",pictureDataString]]; 

...other code
```

After generating my entire xml I am using the following code:

```
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@UploadMemory];

serviceRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[serviceRequest setShouldStreamPostDataFromDisk:YES];
[serviceRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml"];
[serviceRequest appendPostData:[xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[serviceRequest setTimeOutSeconds:86400];
[serviceRequest setDelegate:self];
[serviceRequest startAsynchronous];
```

I even tried to split the `NSData` instance into multiple parts and send separate XML files to the server so I can save my time and be able to upload large video files to the server, but I'm still not able to do so successfully.

It take ages while the encoding the data to base64 so I am not able to split the encoded string in order to send multiple xml to server. Please, suggest a better way to do this.

I have one more option in mind for this if some one can tell me how to read data files in binary format in iOS so I can read video file in binary split that make `NSData` and then convert it to base64encoding so that may work.

Many thanks ....

Comment: Why are you trying to send it as `text/xml` rather than say `video/mp4`?

Comment: Also - you said you've tried a lot of different approaches, can you talk more about what hasn't worked so we don't bombard you with questions about "why not do it like..." when you've already tried that.

Comment: @Carl Veazey what happening is I am not able to convert `NSData` into `base64Encoding` string.My app stop responding when uploading file more than 5 mins.So is their any other better way to do so.

Comment: I'm confused. You say in your question that you're uploading the videos as base 64 encoded strings.  Now you say you're not able to do that?

Comment: @Carl Veazey sorry for the confusion.What I am saying is I have successfully uploaded and converted video with length less than 5 min.But for the video more than 5 min my app just stop responding while it convert `NSData` to `base64Encoding`

Comment: Right. So would you explain please why you have to use base 64 in the first place?

Comment: @Carl Veazey I am new in the i-phone app development I did some research so I found that this is how video should be uploaded on server.Send `base64Encoding` to server through `xml` and regenerate the video at server end.I am doing same process while uploading images to server. Please correct me if I am doing it in wrong manner.

Comment: That is very surprising to me, what source told you to do that? Usually you'd set the content type appropriately And append unencoded data to the request.

Comment: @Carl Veazey thanks for your quick response.Can you please provide me with some sample code.That will be great help for me.

Comment: I have to sleep but will try to put something together tomorrow.

Comment: @Carl Veazey thanks I will wait for your reply.

Comment: I don't have any sample code for you yet but here's the gist of it - use a stream to upload rather than an `NSData` so you don't have to load the entire video into memory at once. Also set the `Content-Type` to be appropriate to your video file. Do you have to submit other form information too? If so you'll need to do a multipart form type thing, which sorry I'm not too experienced with either. Hope this helps!

Comment: @RohitSD Did u find any solution to bind large data to service, Im also facing same problem, could u plz help me if v have any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you are doing the encoding on the main thread? If so, the watchdog timer on iOS after a given amount of time could have decided your app has crashed  and booted your process out. If that's the case you'll need to do your encoding on a background process.